# Unable to find the poles of a function similar to gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, singularity

I am unable to get correct answer of this problem and so I am posting here to know I am making a conceptual mistake as I am unable to get a correct answer despite trying 3 times.

> Question is - prove that poles of function are integer k$\geq$ n given a >15.
>
> Function is  $$-\frac { {\Gamma(nz) }^{a+3} × {\Gamma(n- nz +1) }^3 {\Gamma(nz+2n+1) }^3 } { {\Gamma(nz+n+1)^{a+3}} } $$ .

I   tried to used the fact that $\Gamma(s) $ has poles has 0,-1, -2 ,... and then converting it to ns+0 , ns+1,... in the denominator of $\Gamma(ns) $  and similarly for other terms in Gamma function but still unable to get the answer. I think I am doing something wrong. Can anybody please help.

I shall be really grateful.

Comment: Are you certain that the formula is typed correctly?  I don't get anything like this.  In particular are all the exponents correct?

Comment: @saulspatz I checked it once again. The formula typed is correct. Can you please tell what answer you got?

Comment: $z=-\frac{1}{n}$ looks like a pole

Comment: @Conrad But due to sin(πz) every integer is also a pole

Comment: @Conrad can you please look at the this related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539200/unable-to-think-how-to-calculate-given-residue-of-a-function

Comment: @Conrad can you please answer in detail for this question?

Comment: I would look at this problem if I would understand the precise statement as the current formulation is unclear since the function above has non-integer poles. Do you want to prove that the poles to the right of $n$ are integers and only integers or something else? Also is $n$ a positive integer or can it take negative values?

Comment: @Conrad it has to be shown that only poles are k$\geq$ n. and n belongs to integer greater than or equal to 0 . I hope it's clear now. Actually, it's a part of my presentation which is due, can you please help if you have some spare time. I don't see a way out.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be correct as stated

Comment: @Conrad there was error in defining contour. I was confused due to the paper being in another language and google translator making errors. I am really sorry for inconvenience caused.

Comment: no problem - as noted the statement was not true so there must have been an error somewhere; glad you found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't complete the problem, but I'll show you what I did.  You'll find it straightforward to carry on, I think.

Let the given function be $f(z)$.  In the denominator, repeatedly use the formula $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ to get $$
\Gamma^{a+3}(nz+n+1)=\Gamma^{a+3}(nz)\prod_{k=0}^n(nz+k)^{a+3}\tag1$$

Similarly, in the numerator we get $$
\Gamma^3(nz+2n+1)=\Gamma^3(nz)\prod_{k=0}^{2n}(nz+k)^3\tag2$$ and $$
\Gamma^3(1-nz+n)=\Gamma^3(1-nz)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-nz+k)^3\tag3$$

Now we use Euler's reflection formula $$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac\pi{\sin{\pi z}}$$ together with $(1),(2)\text{ and }(3)$ to get $$
f(z)=-\frac{\pi^3\prod_{k=0}^{2n}(nz+k)^3\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-nz+k)^3}{\sin^3(n\pi z)\prod_{k=0}^n(nz+k)^{a+3}}\tag4$$

At this point, I stopped, because it's hopeless to prove the claim.  Clearly, $z=-\frac1n$ is a zero of order $a+3$ of the denominator, and there simply can't be enough zeros of the numerator to cancel them all.

It should be simple to use $(4)$ to discover the location and order of all the poles and zeros, if you think it worthwhile.

Comment: but every integer is also a pole due to sin(πz) being in denominator

Comment: can you please look at this question if you have some spare time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539200/unable-to-think-how-to-calculate-given-residue-of-a-function

Comment: @XWLPDK When you say "poles of the function are integers ..." I think it is generally understood to mean that these are all the poles.  Anyway, that's how I understood the question.  However, if it means that "all integers satisfying blah blah are poles", you should be able to prove that from the equations above.  Note that it's not enough  to say every integer gives a zero of the denominator, since that may cancel with a zero of the numerator.

Comment: can you please look at above mentioned question in comments.

Comment: @XWLPDK Substitute $nz$ for $z$ in the formula.

Comment: was just wanted to confirm. Thanks!!

Comment: there was some error in defining contour but problem is now solved due to your hints. Thanks. I am really sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I am sorry , the paper was in another language and google translate was not clear. I am sorry.